# What forms of democracy allocate variable numbers of votes to their citizens?

Tags: political-philosophy, democracy

Some are pointing out that democracy with equal vote is not optimal and they propose that people should have variable numbers of votes based on their education, usefulness or other social factors.

What is the name of this idea? What other variants does it have?

Comment: "Some are pointing out…" - Who?

Comment: Though "Some" does seem vague, I think this may have been intentional to avoid a political debate that wouldn't be pertinent in regards to answering the question.

Comment: I would be more specific if I knew more. Sorry for the formulation, I am not native speaker. Should I have used the wording "I have heard somewhere..."?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the idea is "weighted voting."

There are a large number of proposed ways to weight the votes: contribution-based allocation, education-based allocation, occupation-based allocation, etc.

What these variants all have in common is that they are running counter to the "one person-one vote" notion, which has been historically expanding through the notion of universal suffrage.

Comment: any resources pls?

Comment: Schwartzberg's weighted voting (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzberg's_weighted_voting)